# How can I use Model and viewModel in one file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a newbie learning MVC.

I have the below code in a file

```
@model  MVCLearn.Models.Customer
@{
    Layout = null;
}    
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>entercustomer</title>
</head>V
<body>
    <div> 
        @using (Html.BeginForm("submit","Customer",FormMethod.Post))
        {
    <i> Customer code:-</i>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.customercode) <br/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.customercode) <br/>
    <i> Customer name</i> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.customername)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.customername) <br/>
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
        }
        <br/>         
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i want to add  a viewModel to the same page for eg: if the customer name not starts with capital letters needs to show a message.
I wrote a logic in a viewmodel MVCLearn.Models.CustomerVM  .
 How can I add viewmodel to this? 
when i add the same to the view Iam getting error " Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file."
How can i add a model and viewmodel in a file?

Please help.

Comment: You don't use a data model **and** a view model in the view. Just the view model. Your view model contains the same properties as the model (just those that are needed in the view) and are decorated with the validation attributes you need.

Comment: @stephen Muecke I agree. But if i need to write a presentation logic, how can i handle the situation without code on view?

Comment: So i cant use model and viewmodel in one page?

Comment: What presentation logic are you referring to? And have you created a `ValidationAttribute` for validating the `customername` property begins with a capital letter?

Comment: i need to show the text color varies with respect to the name enters. yes i created validation attribute for customername in model.

Comment: Then your view model should be `public class CustomerVM { public string customercode { get; set; };  [yourValidationAttribute]public string customername { get; set; }; }` and in the view its `@model CustomerVM`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91679/discussion-between-user833985-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tuple in MVC like below code...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var first = new FirstModel();
        var second = new SecondModel();

        return View(Tuple.Create(first,second));
    }
}

@model Tuple<FirstModel, SecondModel>

<div> 
    @Model.Item1.FirstModelProp
    @Model.Item2.SecondModelProp
</div>
```

I think it will help you.